# Is there a cost overhead to using transactions rather than sets in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm laying the foundation for all the server interactions in my game and i want to prevent myself from unnecessary high bills(previous game had over 180M+ gameplays)

In this particular game users can create levels and share them with each other. I want to keep track of the amount of gameplays on each level and thought about using transactions for this. However since 'gameplays' are not the most important metric i wondered what kind of overhead this ads in terms of costs when using transactions? And what is the trade-off when using just sets (i will probably lose a % of gameplays right?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont pay for cpu usage in firebase. Therefore using transactions vs sets will not affect your billing.

You will pay for the amount of data saved/downloaded.